# Making webpack and CRA emit files in watch mode

Tags: webpack, create-react-app

I'm, trying to make [CRA's `start` script](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/available-scripts/#npm-start) to emit files on changes instead of keeping them in memory.

I'm working to implement Google Chrome Extension so I need files to be flushed to the file system so that Chrome could pick them up. And building each change is not as convenient as an automatic compilation.

I've tried to use [`react-app-rewired`](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired) to override a bunch of props in webpack config, including `mode`, `watch`, and to see 'output.path' but no luck so far.

Or CRA's 'start' script will never emit underlying because the loaders are not tuned to do that?

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 7):

I know this question is already answered and yeah a couple of months ago this worked for me as well

but recently I started a new project where I wanted to couple a react app with express and I tried using the same setup and suddenly got the error below:

```
Invalid options object. Dev Server has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options has an unknown property 'writeToDisk'. These properties are valid:
   object { allowedHosts?, bonjour?, client?, compress?, devMiddleware?, headers?, historyApiFallback?, host?, hot?, http2?, https?, ipc?, liveReload?, magicHtml?, onAfterSetupMiddleware?, onBeforeSetupMiddleware?, onListening?, open?, port?, proxy?, server?, setupExitSignals?, setupMiddlewares?, static?, watchFiles?, webSocketServer? }
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Since this QA has helped me back then I decided to share what I found here for anyone who is reading this in future and is getting the same error.

### Solution

There seems to be some changes to webpack config "devserver" structure which you can find here: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/

Where you can not use writeToDisk directly anymore and need to put it in a **devMiddleware** object like below:

```js
    module.exports = {
        devServer: {
            devMiddleware: {
                writeToDisk: true,
            },
        },
        //...
    }
```

I am using: `craco: ^6.4.3`

I hope this helps someone who faced the same issue as me

Answer (score 4):

You may need [CRACO](https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco).

> Create React App Configuration Override is an easy and comprehensible configuration layer for create-react-app.

```sh
$ npm install @craco/craco --save
```

Create a `craco.config.js` file in the root directory and configure CRACO:

```
my-app
├── node_modules
├── craco.config.js
└── package.json
```

Update `package.json`:

```
/* package.json */

"scripts": {
-   "start": "react-scripts start",
+   "start": "craco start",
-   "build": "react-scripts build",
+   "build": "craco build"
-   "test": "react-scripts test",
+   "test": "craco test"
}
```

Finally, edit `craco.config.js` file:

```js
module.exports = {
  devServer: (devServerConfig) => {
    devServerConfig.writeToDisk = true;
    return devServerConfig;
  },
};
```

Comment: thank you, with try to use craco, but I've tried the same idea with react-app-rewired and it did not quite work anyway.

Comment: It did not work out. CRA start script just does not want to do some of the stuff that build script does. In the end, I've yanked the CRA and build my project from scratch. Much more control over what is going on, and I can always look into CRA to pick good bits.

Comment: I got it to work by using the direct configuration (https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco/blob/master/packages/craco/README.md#direct-configuration-object-literal)

Comment: This should be marked as the right answer.